# ClickOnce check updates starting from next version

Tags: .net, clickonce

A bit of background: my company is moving file distribution server names for whatever reason. We publish all our apps to `\\SrvA\distribution`, and starting Monday the server will change name to `\\SrvB\\distribution`, with no period of overlapping names. It's the same physical server, but the name is different.

Now, publishing to `\\SrvA\distribution` is trivial, I set the Publishing Folder Location to the correct path on it and everything else is left blank and it just works.

What I want to do is publish an update on `\\SrvA\distribution` right now that will make ClickOnce check the new location instead from then on. It will do nothing until Monday when the new server is up and it can get the next new version with the `\\SrvB\distribution` publish path and everything will work fine.

What actually happens if I set the update path to `\\SrvB\distribution` however is that it's checking it *before downloading the application*, thus finding nothing (the path doesn't exist). And Monday, when the old file server is going to be down, there will be no link to forward it anymore, so this solution won't work.

I also can't do anything about the server migration procedure, so any solution will have to be done in code.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the exact same issue recently.

1. I published the new version to the old location \\serverOld\distrib which update location point changed to \\serverNew\distrib
2. Update didn't work though, cause it immediately looked at the new location

So the only option for me was to keep 2 servers up for a while.

Comment: Which is completely out of the question unfortunately. I'm left with posting a proper update on the new server and just mass mailing everyone to use the `.application` launcher to update the app.

Comment: Can you explain a bit the way you solved the issue- you mailed everyone with a link to the new binaries?

Comment: Yep, if you call that a solution. There's nothing else I can do without both servers up at the same time for a period of time.